# Restrict domain of a function?

Tags: functions

I have a function `f[x,y,...,z]` and I want to restrict its range to positive numbers only, `f > 0`. `f[x,y,...,z]` is multivalued for some `x,y,...,z` and I cannot plot it for these values. How can I restrict the range?

To clarify, I *don't* want to restrict the range of a plot of the function, I want to restrict the range of the function itself.

I've tried `Assuming[f>0, f[x,y,...,z]=(function)]` but that hasn't helped.

Here is the definition of `f`, which I originally didn't supply because it's rather complicated:

```
f[∏, G, M, v, R, A, L] = Abs[1.` v + (12.355667760004051` G M + 1235.5667760004053` M R)/(Sqrt[
  1.` + 0.0001` G^2] (Abs[(994964.5401209999` A^2 G M v)/Sqrt[
     1.` + 0.0001` G^2] + (9.949645401209998`*^7 A^2 M R v)/Sqrt[
     1.` + 0.0001` G^2] - 
     1.0145762999999998`*^7 A^2 \[CapitalPi] + 
     101457.62999999999` A^2 L \[CapitalPi] + \[Sqrt]((1.35`*^7 \(12.023014199999999` A G M + 1202.30142` A M R)^3)/(1.` + 
           0.0001` G^2)^(3/2) + 
        1/(10000.` + 1.` G^2)
          9.899544360981928`*^15 A^4 (1.` G M v + 100.` M R v + 
           0.10197110138986612` Sqrt[
            1.` + 0.0001` G^2] (-99.99999999999999` + 
              1.` L) \[CapitalPi])^2)])^(1/3)) - 1/A 0.004315935432213702` (Abs[(994964.5401209999` A^2 G M v)/Sqrt[
   1.` + 0.0001` G^2] + (9.949645401209998`*^7 A^2 M R v)/Sqrt[
   1.` + 0.0001` G^2] - 1.0145762999999998`*^7 A^2 \[CapitalPi] + 
   101457.62999999999` A^2 L \[CapitalPi] + \[Sqrt]((
      1.35`*^7 (12.023014199999999` A G M + 
         1202.30142` A M R)^3)/(1.` + 0.0001` G^2)^(3/2) + 
      1/(10000.` + 1.` G^2)

        9.899544360981928`*^15 A^4 (1.` G M v + 100.` M R v + 
         0.10197110138986612` Sqrt[
          1.` + 0.0001` G^2] (-99.99999999999999` + 
            1.` L) \[CapitalPi])^2)])^(1/3)];
```

It's negative values of `G` (which are necessary to my project) that make the function multivalued (this is the function that solves $∏ = af^3+bf^2+cf+d$ for appropriate $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$.

This is the plot I am now getting:

[image: http://imgur.com/u4kKd0s]

As you can see *Mathematica* adds a straight line instead of graphing the function when it becomes multivalued. I even asked *Mathematica* for the value of the function at `Pi=100` and got the value of that line, so *Mathematica* is defining the function weirdly, not just plotting it weirdly.

Comment: Without the definition of `f`, it's hard to decide how you would go about doing this.

Comment: I've updated it with the definition of f.

Comment: But in MMA, all of the functions that you've shown are single-valued. It's hard to parse that expression of course, but is it that sometimes there are square roots of negative numbers?

Comment: Since you're solving a cubic, did you look at the discriminant already?

Comment: After checking a bit based on this, it's solving for the principal root of the cubed roots rather than the real-valued one. It now plots, but it's still having an issue plotting the multi-valuedness. I'm not sure what exactly in the function lets it be multivalued, but it definitely us as the graph should be a sideways cubic function. I've uploaded a picture (in which f=V).

Comment: My idea is to define another function G, that it is only defined for positive values of F, like for instance: `F[x_, y_] := x - y;`
`G[x_, y_] /; F[x, y] > 0 := F[x, y]`

Comment: Yeah, MMA seems to return the principal root when presented in this form. One possibility, perhaps, is to have MMA `Solve` the original cubic equation, which will return a list of three `Root` objects. You can then evaluate that list for your choice of parameters, and choose the one that ends up being real (and positive). As it is, I don't think there's any way to directly game your expression so that it will return anything other than the principal root.

Comment: @dionys Why did you change "range" to "domain" in the title?? This seems to be wrong!

Comment: @sebhofer As I read the question, "restrict the range of the function itself" means changing the domain over which the function is defined, thus it seems more clear to me as it's written now. If you feel strongly about it, by all means, edit the question ... even better, answer the question and explain your view.

Comment: @dionys I can only guess what the OP really wants, and I certainly don't have an answer to his question. Fact is that he states twice in his post that he is trying to restrict the range of a function, not the domain. So changing "range" to "domain" in the title, but keeping the original wording in the body doesn't help to clarify the question. If anything it adds to the confusion as now one needs to figure out where the two contradicting statements came from.

Comment: @sebhofer I still don't agree, but I think I see where you're coming from. In grade-school math it's common that range and domain just refer to the x and y axes ... while here, I meant domain in the sense of an [open connected set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Domain.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but maybe this version of OP's function can be of use. The code in the question seems to have some artifacts that won't allow it to parse.

```
velocityAtPower[power_, grade_, mass_, windspeed_, resistance_, area_, losses_]:= windspeed-(1/area)(0.004315935432213702*Abs[-1.0145762999999998*^7*area^2*power+101457.63*area^2*losses*power+(994964.540121*area^2*grade*mass*windspeed)/Sqrt[1+0.0001*grade^2]+(9.949645401209998*^7*area^2*mass*resistance*windspeed)/Sqrt[1+0.0001*grade^2]+Sqrt[(1.35*^7*(12.0230142*area*grade*mass+1202.30142*area*mass*resistance)^3)/(1+0.0001*grade^2)^(3/2)+(9.899544360981928*^15*area^4*(0.10197110138986612*Sqrt[1+0.0001*grade^2]*(losses-100)*power+grade*mass*windspeed+100*mass*resistance*windspeed)^2)/(10000+grade^2)]]^(1/3))+(12.355667760004051*grade*mass+1235.5667760004053*mass*resistance)/(Sqrt[1+0.0001*grade^2]*Abs[-1.0145762999999998*^7*area^2*power+101457.63*area^2*losses*power+(994964.5401209999*area^2*grade*mass*windspeed)/Sqrt[1+0.0001*grade^2]+(9.949645401209998*^7*area^2*mass*resistance*windspeed)/Sqrt[1+0.0001*grade^2]+Sqrt[(1.35*^7*(12.0230142*area*grade*mass+1202.30142*area*mass*resistance)^3)/(1+0.0001*grade^2)^(3/2)+(9.899544360981928*^15*area^4*(0.10197110138986612*Sqrt[1+0.0001*grade^2]*(losses-100)*power+grade*mass*windspeed+100*mass*resistance*windspeed)^2)/(10000+grade^2)]]^(1/3))//Abs

velocityAtPower[100, -5, 82, 0, 0.003, 0.315, 3]
(*16.1447*)
```

Here's the code for OP's plot showing the issue with negative grade (G in the code above):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[velocityAtPower[P, G, M, v, R, A, L], {P, 0, 1500},
   PlotRange -> {-25, 25}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Power (W)", "Velocity (m/s)"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Velocity at Power, P"],
 {{G, 0, "Grade (%)"}, -20, 20},
 {{M, 82, "Total Mass (kg)"}, 50, 125},
 {{v, 0, "Wind Velocity (m/s)"}, -25, 25},
 {{A, 0.315, "Effective Frontal Area (m^2)"}, 0.1, 1},
 {{L, 3, "Drivetrain Loss (%)"}, 0, 5},
 {{R, 0.003, "Coeff. of Rolling Resistance"}, 0.001, 0.006}]
```

The trouble seems to arise when this sub-expression under the square root goes negative:

```
Module[{f, vals = {power -> 100, mass -> 82, windspeed -> 0, resistance -> 0.003, area -> 0.315, losses -> 3}},
 f = (1.35*^7 * (12.0230142 * area * grade * mass + 1202.30142 * area * mass * resistance)^3)/(1 + 0.0001 * grade^2)^(3/2) +
     (9.899544360981928*^15 * area^4 * (0.10197110138986612 * Sqrt[1 + 0.0001*grade^2] * (losses - 100) * power + grade * mass * windspeed + 100 * mass * resistance * windspeed)^2)/(10000 + grade^2);
  f = f/.vals;
  Plot[f, {grade, -10, 10}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After supplying definitions of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, just define

```
f[pi_, G_, M_, v_, R_, A_, L_] = 
  With[{a = (*your defn here*),
        b = (*your defn here*),
        c = (*your defn here*),
        d = (*your defn here*),},
    Root[a #^3 + b #^2 + c # + d - pi &,1]];
```

In the documentation for `Root`, the solutions are ordered so that real roots come first (provided the $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real, I think).

So unless there is something really strange going on, this should yield correct results even when `pi` is taken small.